# Redefined function ( virtual ) in polymorphism with different number of arguments

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Suppose I have a class of particles:

```
class Particle {

public:
  virtual void SetLorenzVector( Vector3&, double M ); 

protected:
  LorenzVector P;
};
```

And also I have a derived class of photons:

```
class Photons : public Particles {

public:
  virtual void SetLorentzVector ( Vector3&, /*double M = 0*/ );
};
```

In `Photons` class I want to have redefined function
`SetLorentzVector`, but I do not want to perform the second argument there (because it is always equal to 0).
Is there an elegant way to do this in `C++` style?

Default argument is valid? If so, NOTE, that in base class I want `SetLorentzVector` to require exactly 2 arguments.

Comment: What is wrong with `default argument` ?

Comment: A default argument is valid, but you'd still need to pass it if you have a `Particles*`, so that doesn't really look like it should be a virtual override.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes. It seems like you`re right.

Comment: Side note: if `SetLorentzVector` with an arbitrary `M` doesn't make sense for all subclasses, the base class interface itself seems a bit iffy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to override the method, it must have the same signature, which includes arguments. It means, that in this case there will be 2 arguments. And yes, default arguments are valid, but that won't help you if you have Particles*, as @molbdnilo mentioned. If you want, you can check, that argument value is 0, in the body of the method.
Otherwise, you can create a new method with different signature, i.e. with 1 argument, but you'll be able to use it only with Photons*.
Anyway, it depends on the way you are going to use these classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Particle {

public:
  void SetLorenzVector( Vector3&, double M ); // should it really be virtual?
  virtual void SetLorenzVector( Vector3&) = 0;

protected:
  LorenzVector P;
};

class Photons : public Particles {

public:
  virtual void SetLorentzVector ( Vector3& v) {SetLorentzVector(v, 0.)};
};
```